# Send multiple messages with firebase (over than 500.000 messages)

Tags: firebase

I need to send `1.000.000` messages with firebase.

I want to send a `hash` with the user IDs of an application that I use today to send the mobile push notifications to android and iOS devices.

I want to send all IDs in one request to firebase, and the firebase sends the push notifications to me... It is possible?

Comment: You should give more details on what you plan to implement: which kind of messages (email/smartphone notifications)? what IDs? etc... If I may, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much u know about push notification but I will try to help,
You could do like below:

1)Your user subscribes to a specific topic

```
public void onTokenRefresh(){
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
    //FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news");

}
```

this method should be in a class which extends FirebaseInstanceIdService.
And you can send refreshedToken to server. You can use that tokens to send notification to specific user or all users.

2)
     `$fields = array(
                'to' => '/topics/news',
                'data' => array(
                    'title' => 'Title', 
                    'body' => 'bodyMessage',
                    'sound' => '1',
                    'vibrate' => '1',
                    'LargeIcon' => 'ic_launcher')
           );`

When u do like this your all user subscribes at installation, after that u can send messages via a web services.

By the way if you want to send notification on app is background also you should use 'data' keyword in JSON object. Otherwise just you can use 'notification' instead 'data' keyword.